# PHP SQL Query to separate multiple columns (in row) into separate rows

Tags: php, sql, select, mariadb

I have a table listing test results for students. Each row contains a student id in one column and there are 16 columns each representing a separate test score. I need to now create a query that allows me to see the student ID with a separate row for each test score. I have searched Stack Overflow for the best way to do this but I am not finding anything that looks efficient. I came up with the code listed below for one student (1000002) but it seems overly complicated for what I'm trying to accomplish plus it's only for three of the test scores so I would have to add much more to this to get all 16. Is there an easy way to do this through a single query (prefered) or do I need to pull the row and then use a loop to build an array from each element (less prefered)?

```
SELECT 
   scores_uid
 , score1
FROM 
 assessment_scores WHERE fk_assigned_uid = '1000002'

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
   scores_uid
 , score2
FROM 
 assessment_scores WHERE fk_assigned_uid = '1000002'

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
   scores_uid
 , score3
FROM 
 assessment_scores WHERE fk_assigned_uid = '1000002';
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hello. MariaDB accessed through PHP

Comment: I can't help thinking that a separate table for the scores might make this job easier, and certainly would help if you get to a point where there might be more than 16 scores.

Comment: @ND_Coder he asked which database system you are using so like mysql mariadb sql server and so on  also add table + data and wanted result

Comment: @nbk sorry, but I am not understanding what is required. I am fairly new to this but I'll try. I am using mysql on a Digital Ocean server with a MariaDB database.  Does this help?

Comment: @droopsnoot I understand your approach but because there will never be more than 16 test scores for this application, adding another table for this didn't seem necessary. Maybe my newness is part of the problem but is there a way to accomplish what I would like to do with the existing table structure?

Comment: Why is the test ID not a separate column?
That way each student can have 16 test entries each with their own result, instead of 1 entry with all 16 test results

Comment: @ND_Coder  we need to help you a CREATE tABLE assessment_scores  with data in it (INSERT INTO assessment_scores ..) and from that data which result you expect. please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for more information and sometomes it helpsm to read the tag descrion

Comment: `adding another table for this didn't seem necessary`...the point is, with nbk's suggested approach it _doesn't matter_ how many test scores there are, whether it's 0, 1, 16 or 20,000. You don't have to change the design just to add a test, and also you can easily get the data out in rows properly. Ultimately, what nbk suggested is standard database normalisation techniques, which I'd hope you'd have been taught when learning about databases and how to design them (hopefully you studied this _before_ trying to design a database!?!). Your current design is denormalised and hence causes issues

Comment: So, I'm starting to think that there is no 'best' way to handle this because it all comes back to my bad design and that another table is required. Is that correct? If so, I will go back and do it over.

Comment: Yes. It will be a lot easier if you normalise the database schema properly. It will also help to avoid other types of related problems in future.

Comment: Understood. I appreciate the input very much. While I do understand the 'normalization' schema (and this is used in my other tables), I was trying - what I thought might be a simpler method - but good learning for me. Thank you!

Comment: Agreed with others that a separate table is the best way to go from a data perspective. But you should also understand that you don't actually need a query that generates 16 rows of results in order to create an HTML table with 16 rows in it. You could have one result row per student, iterate over those rows, and within that loop iterate over the 16 result fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you'd have something like this

`students`

- `id`
- `name`

`tests`

- `id`
- `number`

`test_results`

- `id`
- `student_id`
- `test_id`
- `result`

This way you can query on all results of a student in one query.

```
SELECT test_results.result AS Result,
 students.name as Student,
 tests.number as Testnumber 
FROM test_results 
LEFT JOIN students ON students.id = test_results.student_id
LEFT JOIN tests ON tests.id = test_results.test_id
WHERE student_id = {{id}}
```